# Adding variables of different classes to List of another class

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, console-application, c#-3.0

```cs
public class Project
{
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string Startdate { get; set; }
    public string Enddate { get; set; }
    public int? id { get; set; }

    public Project(string projectname, string startdate, string enddate, int Id)
    {
        this.ProjectName = projectname;
        this.Startdate = startdate;
        this.Enddate = enddate;
        this.id = Id;
    }

    public Project()
    {
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public int roleid { get; set; }
    public string roleName { get; set; }


    public Employee(int empid, string FirstName, string LastName, string Email, string Mobile, string Address, int ROleID, string ROlename)
    {
        EmployeeID = empid;
        firstName = FirstName;
        lastName = LastName;
        email = Email;
        mobile = Mobile;
        address = Address;
        roleid = ROleID;
        roleName = ROlename;
    }

    public Employee()
    {
    }
}

public class AddEmptoProject
{
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    Project projecting = new Project();
    Employee employing = new Employee();

    public AddEmptoProject(string projectName, int employeeID)
    {
        this.ProjectName = projectName;
        projectName = projecting.ProjectName;
        this.EmployeeID = employeeID;
        employeeID = employing.EmployeeID;
    }

    public AddEmptoProject()
    {
    }
}

public class AddingEmptoProject
{
    public List<AddEmptoProject> AddingEmplist = new List<AddEmptoProject>();

    public void addingemp(AddEmptoProject add)
    {
        AddingEmplist.Add(add);
    }
}

//This part of code will be in main method
var PROJname = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter the id of employee to add into project");
int EMPID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
AddEmptoProject ADDTOPROJ = new AddEmptoProject();
Project ADDTOPROJ1 = new Project();
Employee EMPIDD = new Employee();

if(PROJname.Equals(ADDTOPROJ1.ProjectName) && EMPID.Equals(EMPIDD.EmployeeID))
{
    AddEmptoProject YADD = new AddEmptoProject(PROJname, EMPID);
    AddingEmptoProject addition = new AddingEmptoProject();
    addition.addingemp(YADD);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Entry bro");
}
```

I am new to C#

I am trying to build a console application

In this everything seems to work fine but the if statement will does not execute

what is the error here ?

Is there any other way better than this ?

If possible can someone explain me the right way to add variables of different classes into List of another class

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve] - you've posted nearly 100 lines of code, most of which are probably irrelevant to the problem. But how would you expect `ADDTOPROJ1.ProjectName` to be equal to `PROJname` when you never set it anywhere? (I'd strongly encourage you to read about C# naming conventions too, btw.)

Comment: In addition to the issue of the project name properties not being set, there are a number of methods that you are bringing over from the java world that have been replaced with better options in .net. I highly recommend the use of the static `string.Equals()` for string comparison, while the int comparisons can be done with `==`. Additionally, always prefer to use the `.TryParse()` methods for parsing to a type: they return a bool so they can be baked right into control flow, while the parsed variable is an out parameter `if (int.TryParse(userInput, out int empId)) {}`

Comment: You just created new instances of Project and Employee [ADDTOPROJ1 = new Project(); Employee EMPIDD = new Employee();]. You must assign values to them before using it inside if.